# Delete duplicate values from mysql using sql queries/php

Tags: php

I have a column of website-urls in my MySQL table.
How can I remove all the duplicate rows only using sql queries (in php) ?

OR select only the UNIQUE records and add it into another table again using sql queries in php.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to select unique records you could use DISTINCT like this

```
SELECT DISTINCT c1, c2, c3 FROM t1
WHERE c1 > const;
```

If you need to insert into another table you could use

```
INSERT INTO t2
SELECT DISTINCT c1, c2, c3 FROM t1
WHERE c1 > const;
```

The table t2 must have the same number and type of columns in t1

The code in PHP:

```
<?php
$query=mysql_query("INSERT INTO t2
SELECT DISTINCT c1, c2, c3 FROM t1
WHERE c1 > const");
?>
```